# python sum() function returning [TypeError: 'str' object is not callable] when used

Tags: python, sum, typeerror

I made a code that reads a file and prints the sum of all the numbers contained in the file.

for example a txt file that contains(text.txt)

```
10in the 134 fill23
and 100cars 3in 42
```

will return 312

First I made a short code that looks like this

```
import re

f = open("text.txt")
numbs = re.findall('[0-9]+', f.read())
numbsls = []

for i in range(0,len(numbs)): numbsls.append(int(numbs[i]))
print(sum(numbsls))
```

This code worked fine. Next, I modified the code so that it would read the text line by line. (for further flexibility in processing later) It looks like this.

```
import re

f = open("text.txt")
t = True
numbsls = []

for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    numbs = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    if t:
        sum = line
        t = False
    for i in range(0,len(numbs)):
        numbsls.append(int(numbs[i]))

print(sum(numbsls))
```

but when I ran the code it returned this traceback

`line 16, in <module> print(sum(numbsls)) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

I checked some articles and other stackoverflow questions regarding to this problem with no luck. To me everything looks fine and I can't spot what's wrong.

Any help or feedback would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `sum = line` will override the built-in function `sum()`. Not sure what the idea of `if` is anyway.

Comment: @buran Ah I placed that for checking purposes(I must've forgotten to remove it) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

sum is an in-built function in python, you should not use it as a variable. The line `sum=line` is creating the issue. You can use variable `total` instead of sum.